# Custom php code in joomla 2.5 component

Tags: joomla

Hello is there any way to use a custom php code as component, in joomla 1.5 I was using Joomla PHP Pages Component from http://www.fijiwebdesign.com/products/joomla-php-pages.html.

With this component I could assign a php file to any menu and execute any php command including query to select/insert/update database.

Unfortunately is not updated to work with joomal 2.5

Is there any other component or tricks to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check following links ?

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023
- http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jincludes
- http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/DirectPHP-plugin.php
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules/6474
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules/15251
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules/4971
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/5051

Comment: is it not possible to add php WITHOUT some 3rd party extension? I really do not want to add more and more and more layers.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/). Its very quick, and you can even make fully functioning database applications in a jiffy

It comes with a few small bugs I noticed of which the one to mention is the fact that the default.xml on components/com_YOURCOM/views/YOURTHING/tmpl is not generated... So you have to add that otherwise it doesnt show up as a choice for a menu-item-type.

The default.xml only needs something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="YOURNAME">
            <message>YOUR AWESOME component.</message>
    </layout>
</metadata>
```

Good luck!